# ERB options_for_select with padrino/sinatra

Tags: ruby, erb

I am trying to make select in form, but it is not working for me, I tried

```
<%= f.select :children, options_for_select(@children.collect { |child| [child.name, child.id]}) %>
```

And

```
@children.collect { |child| [child.name, child.id]})
```

this is perfectly working for me in pry.

```
=> [["Peter", 1],
 ["John", 2],
 ["Trish", 3],
```

But it is still failing on

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of Array into Hash:
```

I am little bit lost :(

Have you got any tips please?

============
EDIT:

It is in this form

```
<% error = @class.errors.key?(:children) && @article.errors[:children].count > 0 %>
<fieldset class='control-group <%= error ? 'has-error' : ''%>'>
  <%= f.label :children, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class='controls'>
    <% @children = Children.all %>
    <%= f.select :children, options_for_select(@children.collect { |child| [child.name, child.id]}) %>
    <span class='help-inline'><%= error ? f.error_message_on(:children) : "Ex: Article category" %></span>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<% @author = session[:account_id] %>
<%= f.hidden_field :author, :value => @author %>
<input name="author" form='article' type="hidden" value="4" />

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.submit pat(:save), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  &nbsp;
  <%= f.submit pat(:save_and_continue), :class => 'btn btn-info', :name => 'save_and_continue' %>
  &nbsp;
  <%= link_to pat(:cancel), url(:articles, :index), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
</div>
```

The form is invoked by

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li> <%= link_to tag_icon(:list, pat(:list)), url(:articles, :index) %></li>
  <li class="active"> <%= link_to tag_icon(:plus, pat(:new)), url(:articles, :new) %></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <% form_for :article, url(:articles, :create), :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
    <%= partial 'articles/form', :locals => { :f => f } %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

And it is called from controller, I don't know how to put this out a little bit more, it is based on db models, they return data as I wrote, but this form is not working. I tried to write new part of the form, and yet the problem again.

---

I tried to use only html form, but I cannot tell the select to send data via POST, I am very weak in webmastering, I am only programmer. Maybe that is the way, but I dont know how to make it right, when I put

and values (there I was able to generate proper select. But it didnt sent any data.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `options_for_select([["Peter", 1], ["John", 2], ["Trish", 3]])
=> "<option value=\"1\">Peter</option>\n<option value=\"2\">John</option>\n<option value=\"3\">Trish</option>"` ... Can you please provide a [mcve]? The example you have given above works perfectly.

Comment: Oh, for me its still failing, it is used in admin generated from Padrino, I will try to post more code, but it is hooked in huge project. Will post in a moment

Comment: What is `@children`? You haven't show where this is defined in your code. I'm also confused by the line: `@categories = Children.all` -- you're not using the `@categories` variable anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake, from GIT when I copied form from another `@children` is variable which contains Children.all from model Children, where are values including name and id, so it has to be `@children = Children.all`.

Comment: When I call `@children = Children.all` and `@children.collect { |child| [child.name, child.id]})` over it I get result as I wrote before, but in form it fails

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the error? Because this code, in isolation, works fine. I don't know how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes I am sure it fails exactly on this line of my form and it is error from this file  `2017-10-18 09:41:04 - TypeError - no implicit conversion of Array into Hash:
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/padrino-helpers-0.14.1.1/lib/padrino-helpers/form_builder/abstract_form_builder.rb:317:in `update'`

Comment: Now I separated that form just for that one line, and it fails on the template rendering on this type

Comment: One last time I will say, I cannot help without a reproducible example. I don't know how that error correlates to the code above. The code: `@children.collect { |child| [child.name, child.id]})` works fine, unless `@children` is something different to what you are telling me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem, I googled another style of usage

```
f.select(:state, :collection => @states, :fields => [:name, :id])
```

and I put the data from model directly into form and it works. The documentation about forms I used was constructed the other way using arrays and hashes, this is better way.

Thanks!